# Could I put an arduino in series with a battery charger?

Tags: arduino-nano, power, battery, voltage, electricity

recently in one of my projects I have wanted to make battery powered. I was wondering if I could connect the charger to the battery and the battery to the Arduino without blowing it. The battery is 12v 7.2 Ah and the charger is 12v 1 A.

(See attached)

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you have and what you want to do. You can also draw a schematic do be more clear.

Comment: I added the picture. Do I need something like a diode or just wire everything together like the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for clarity: your diagram shows the Arduino, the batteries, and the charger connected in *parallel* - which is correct for what you want to do. However, a 12v power supply (batteries, charger, or both) are at, or very close to the maximum input voltage spec the Uno. The Uno's voltage regulator has to waste - as heat - a good deal of power in reducing the voltage to 5v. And if the power supply provides any more than 12 volts, it will exceed regulator's spec.

Update:

> how much do you think it would go over?

We can't know without knowing the specs on the particular batteries and charger. A battery charger has to apply a higher voltage than the present voltage of the battery it is trying to charge, in order to drive current into the battery against its (the battery's) voltage. You need to know more about the charger and the batteries.

Update 2:

> The batteries are 12V 7.2 Ah and they are PK12V7.2 as the product name.

Those Lead/Acid cells. I didn't find a spec for the charger, but  in automotive use, Lead/Acids are charged at 14.2 volts. Your Uno's regulator won't like that. I'm guessing you measured your charger's output voltage with no load.

Try measuring it with the batteries attached and at low, medium, or almost fully charged. That should give you a better idea. We can only guess without the specs but it sounds like these components would be pushing your Uno's regulator pretty hard.

If these components and the Uno part of a system that requires 12v for some other components, I'd suggest using 2 power supplies, 12v for the components that need it, and 7 volts into Vin (or 5v, if well regulated, into the 5v pin) on your Uno. The lower voltage could be supplied by a buck converter powered off of the 12v, which would fairly efficient and require only one charger.

Comment: If it was 12v how much do you think it would go over? The Arduino should take 12v. Do you think there might be any other issues other than the one? The diagram is what I want with 2 batteries and the charger on for a day every two weeks.

Comment: The batteries are 12V 7.2 Ah and they are PK12V7.2 as the product name. The charger is the Motomaster 12V 1A lead acid battery charger.

Comment: The battery charger charges the batteries but is only 11-12 volts on my multimeter. Any other issues that can hurt the arduino like... something?

Comment: 11-12V is much too low for charging a Lead Acid battery. This is bad for your battery and it will probably not hold a charge for long, if you do not charge it to 13.8V (at a minimum) to 14.2V or more soon. Reducing 12V down to the 5V the Arduino needs using the standard on-board linear regulator will waste most power going into the board in the form of heat. This is not only very inefficient but can also overheat the regulator. Use a (much more efficient) buck regulator to regulate the 12V down to 7V (Vin) or 5V.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like I need a regulator and a new battery charger because even with a load it stays at 12V.